# Decrease div width on a bigger parent width

Tags: css

I want a div to maximize size when viewport width is smaller, and reduce size (up to a minimum) when viewport width is larger.

How to achieve that?

```css
.outer {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 128px;
  min-width: 50%;
  /* width: ???; What to set here to achieve the effect? */
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

I tried to modify padding instead of width, but it's still the same effect than setting the width to a % value.

```css
.outer {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 128px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of `width: calc(500px - 20vw)`. The `vw` will by smallest (creating the larger value) when the window is small, with the reverse occurring in a large window.

Comment: Yep, this works. I had to also set `max-width: 100%` since on a small screen it was overflowing.

Comment: Yeah, didn't mention that. Best of luck in whatever you're making!

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS3 @media queries. Check the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media (min-width: 600px) {
                .outer {
                outline: 1px solid red;
                height: 128px;
                max-width: 50%;
                margin: auto;
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                .outer {
                outline: 1px solid red;
                height: 128px;
                width: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This only allows for setting a set number of sizes, rather than gradually changing sizes (which is what I think they want).